# codeigniter structure for models views and controllers

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and I'm creating a blog coded with it for learning, but i have some doubts about the structure.
Right now i have an admin section for login which is working and posts which work too, but i think it can be done better.

The project is in [github](https://github.com/oterox/citinyblog/tree/master/application)

Now it is like this:

```
+Controllers
   +admin
      - users.php (login, logout)
   +posts
      - posts.php (index, new_post, delete_post, edit_post)

+Models
   +admin
      - user.php
   +posts
      - post.php

+Views
   +admin
      - login.php
   +posts
      - post.php
      - post_index.php
      - edit_post.php
      - new_post.php
   +components
      - header.php
      - footer.php
      - mainsidebar.php
```

Is this structure ok or is there a better way of organizing/renaming it?

For the admin area i want to admin posts, should i move the posts views, controller and model to admin folder? or should i have posts in both admin and posts folders?

I'm a little bit lost about where to put the controllers/models/views.

Should i have to edit the routes?

Comment: If you are new to CI, i suggest you to move to FuelPHP because CI stopped development and seeking for new owner.

Comment: I know but most of the php developer jobs are looking for codeigniter developers.I've done a Symfony2 course and created some code but codeigniter is what i need now

Answer (score 0):

Here my suggestion structure

```
 application
     controllers
        admin
           users.php
           posts.php

     models
        admin
           user.php
           post.php

     views
        admin
           user.php
           post.php
```

Comment: and the posts listing in the public side? the views/controller should be inside admin too?I agree with that folder structure for admin part

Comment: the views/controller should be inside admin too?
yes....

for admin works keep all php files inside admin folders...because later u need main site, those are place on outside admin folder 
application---->controllers,application---->models,
application---->views
posts listing listing created on inside those mention folders,not in admin folder....(if u want to manage post listing then create separate controller,view,model in admin folder )